# Doctrine::Windows::How generate Doctrine Models on windows?

Tags: php, windows, doctrine

How generate Doctrine Models from database on windows?
(I working with zend studio and zend framework)

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice command line script called `doctrine` for this task (among others). You may run it by calling `php doctrine [params]` from the command line or creating your own `.bat`, basing on this shell script.

Take a look at Doctrine Sandbox package and Doctrine manual for details.

Comment: With "Composer" installation, from the project root, doctrine 2.3
"vendor\bin\doctrine orm:schema-tool:create"
It looks for cli-config.php

Answer (score 1):

`php doctrine build-schema` is the command to use. See takeshin's answer too.